# Why does GROUP BY give me too high a row count in BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I believe I am missing something (probably quite simple) in the use of **GROUP BY** in BigQuery, and I am hoping someone can set me straight.

Comparing these two queries I get different numbers of users

```
SELECT SUM(users) FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users,
      FROM
        `mytable`
      WHERE
        DATE BETWEEN ('2022-05-01') AND ('2022-05-31')        
      GROUP BY
        DATE
)
```

value for users approx: 140000

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users,
    FROM
      `mytable`
    WHERE
      DATE BETWEEN ('2022-05-01') AND ('2022-05-31')
```

value for users approx: 120000

Comment: It seems that you have duplicate user_ids among different dates, to check, try `select user_id from mytable where date ... group by user_id having count(distinct date)>1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second query you're counting the distinct user_id values in the entire date range. In the first query you're counting the distinct user_id values *for each day* in the range, then summing those. There are probably duplicate users being counted on different days in the first query.